# Disable caching of the config details in Symfony2

Tags: caching, symfony

We have several sites, each site has its own database and url. 
All sites are using an API written by Symfony2. The database configuration in Symfony is in parameter.php file, which set the database parameters according to the current site.

As a result, every request to Symfony can be from different database, which means, the configuration should be loaded every time. 
The question is how to disable the caching of the config parameters.

Or, if there is other idea, how to keep caching and to find a way to create caching per site, I would be happy to hear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a separate cache directory for each site. This way the configuration parameters are saved in the cache per site.

Here is how to override the cache directory:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html

I just added the following to the AppKernel.php file:

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    return $this->rootDir . '/cache/'. $this->environment .'/' . $request->getHost();
}
```